# What is the purpose of += sign to this code, when you can just do + instead?

Tags: javascript, function

I've been watching a javascript tutorial to refresh my knowledge of it.
I just need some guidance on why he decided to use this code "style"

Basically, there's a variable named result with an empty string ("") and I'm not so sure why he used  (result += ...) when he can also use (result = ...) where it showed the same output when I tried.

```
function mySentence(myName, myVerb){
var result = "";
result += myName + " " + myVerb + " towards the tree.";

return result;
}

console.log(mySentence("Dale", "walked"));
```

**vs**

```
function mySentence(myName, myVerb){
var result = "";
result = myName + " " + myVerb + " towards the tree.";

return result;
}

console.log(mySentence("Dale", "walked"));
```

Link of video: https://youtu.be/PkZNo7MFNFg

36:28:00 : Word Blanks

Comment: I suspect you've added an extra `+` there? (Just before `myName`.) *Edit:* [Yup](https://youtu.be/PkZNo7MFNFg?t=2404).

Comment: In this case the person simply decided to write the code that way.

Comment: I don't know why he did this, and it shouldn't be necessary in JavaScript.  In some other languages, e.g. in Java, in cases where `result` might not be defined, it would be necessary.

Comment: You mean you could have just used `=` instead: `var result; result = myName + " " + myVerb + " towards the tree.";` or just `var result = myName + " " + myVerb + " towards the tree.";`

Comment: `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y`. It should be obvious why you might prefer `+=` over repeating `x`…?!

Comment: @tim biegeleisen um ... I don't quite get that point. If a variable wasn't initialized in Java, `+=` is 't possible but `=` is.

Comment: I thought the OP was asking about the unnecessary `var result = ""`

Comment: Hey guys, edited the post, sorry for confusions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `result` is set to `""`, an empty string in the beginning.

When you do `result=` the variable will be replaced with the new value.
But when you do `result+=` the variable does not get replaced. It will be added with the value that already exists.

For example, in your code, if the variable is set to some value in the beginning, like `result="The answer is: "`, then the two styles would yield different results. The `result=` style will return `Dale walked towards the tree.`. And the `result+=` will return `The answer is: Dale walked towards the tree.`

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of for having it there is that the author wanted to be able to rearrange a series of statements after the initial declaration that all used `+=` without having to worry about which was the first statement originally. E.g.:

```
var result = "";

result += "something";
result += "another thing";
result += "yet another thing";
```

...where they may want later to swap things around:

```
var result = "";

result += "another thing";
result += "something";
result += "yet another thing";
```